# xamarin.IOS with Visual studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio community 2015.  I am trying to create IOS application with xamarin, for debugging the application it asks to connect with an Mac machine.  Is there any other way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Xamarin iOS projects in Visual Studio require a Mac build server.

Take a look at the support documentation on how to setup your PC to connect to a Mac for design and debugging: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/

Comment: In Build 2016 they told that they will release an IOS simulator for windows so how it will work.

Comment: You will still need a Mac for the iOS simulator. All of the tools, sdks, and simulators live on the Mac. Apples Eulas state you must compile apps on a physical Mac, so there are several reasons for this. There are also some Mac in cloud solutions, or a cheap Mac mini is always a good option.

Comment: Thanks.  So we need a physical Mac machine